# Create 1km Grid in QGIS from Canada Topo Data

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, canada

I've been struggling with this all day and can't seem to get anywhere, even with the help of other forum posts.  I'm pulling vector data from the [canadian gis](ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/bndt/50k_shp_en/) system, and loading it into QGIS.  That works all fine and dandy and I'm darn near enjoying playing around with the maps.  The problem I have is that I cannot seem to create an accurate 1km square grid.

Generally it seems that a interval of around 0.1 or less is the only way to even have gridlines show up on the screen.  I'm doing this both through the print composer and using the research tools -> vector grid methods.  Both work exactly the same.  From what I understand, living in Saskatchewan I need the UTM 13N projection, so that's what I've been using.

Anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the vector input data? Contours, elevation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a CRS of WGS84, which is EPSG:4326. You need to save as your data into UTM 13N projection, and load that data into fresh QGIS project so it will take by default the projected coordinate of UTM 13 in the QGIS project. Then you can use research tools -> vector grid methods, and choose 1000 (which is 1000 m) grid cell, to create 1 km grid mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly the step I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already projected properly into EPSG:26913 (NAD83/UTM13N) or something equivalent, then your problem might simply be that your project is set to WGS84. One easy way to fix this is to right click on a shape/grid that is in your MTM projection and select "Set Project CRS from Layer".

If you are use the QGIS tool "Create Grid", you can specify the intervals and most importantly, the output CRS. To ensure that you are making the grid in the right place, try using a shape/grid of the area of interest as your bounding box; if the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax coordinates are geographic, you'll need to double-check your project/layer CRS until you start seeing 5- or 6-digit integers.

After that's done, I'd follow ahmadhanb's advice and set an interval of 1000 to specify metres and you'll be set.

Comment: I'd tried doing this a couple times.  The files seem to have been in NAD83-CSRS (not UTM).  I imported them as such, then converted them to NAD83/UTM13N and imported them into a new project.  A bit of a hassle but not too bad.  I need to learn how to use the python console for QGIS so I can just script stuff like this.

Comment: You don't need to script anything though for this. You simply need to ensure that the Project CRS is set to what you'd like it to be. 

In the bottom-right corner you can see what EPSG you're working in. If you click that, you can change your CRS on the fly to whatever you'd like without remaking your project from scratch.